# NSNumberFormatter only display "E" for large/small values?

Tags: swift, macos, nsnumberformatter

I have an `NSTableView` that I populate with numbers. These are often numbers like "1" or "15" that I can display normally. However, a subset of them are always very large or small, like "1.5E8".

I made an NSNumberFormatter singleton so I could use stringFromNumber to format these, but it seems that I can only have E on or off:

[image]

Those "0E0"'s are useless, they should simply be "0". There doesn't *seem* to be a setting for this though. Am I just missing something?

Or do you always have to do this in code?

Here is the setup code in my document subclass:

```
var measurementFormatter: NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
measurementFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
measurementFormatter.numberStyle = .ScientificStyle
measurementFormatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = true
measurementFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
measurementFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6
measurementFormatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = false
```

And an example use:

```
numStr = (document?.measurementFormatter.stringFromNumber(num)!
```

Comment: I never got `E0E` from the `NSNumberFormatter`. Could you should do the code that you are using now?

Comment: Good point, added.

Comment: Are we talking iOS or OS X here? The formatter on OS X is much more powerful (it has `format` property so you could set any format). On iOS the best solution is to either remove `E0` suffix from the result or use two formatters depending on the value.

Comment: That's probably the best solution for OS X, too. You can fix the `0E0` case by replacing the default format with a better format (there are separate formats for positive numbers, negative numbers and zero) but I don't think you can create a format with optional exponent.

Comment: So this is OSX, but it seems there is no way to do this automatically? I did it in code, let's hope the performance is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't claim to be an `NSNumberFormatter` expert - there are too many options to remember. But setting `zeroSymbol` seems to solve your problem:

```
measurementFormatter.zeroSymbol = "0"
```

---

**Edit:** I have spent too much time over this tonight. It seems like there no way to get rid of those `E0`, so I decided to subclass `NSNumberFormatter` instead:

```
class MyNumberFormatter: NSNumberFormatter {
    override func stringFromNumber(number: NSNumber) -> String? {
        guard let str = super.stringFromNumber(number) else {
            return nil
        }
        return str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("E0", withString: "", options: [.AnchoredSearch, .BackwardsSearch], range: str.startIndex..<str.endIndex)
    }
}

var measurementFormatter = MyNumberFormatter()
measurementFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
measurementFormatter.numberStyle = .ScientificStyle
measurementFormatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = true
measurementFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
measurementFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6
measurementFormatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = false

// Examples:
[0, 0.0014, 2, 15, 3.14, 100, 1500000000].forEach {
    print("\($0) --> \(measurementFormatter.stringFromNumber($0)!)")
}
```

Output:

```
0 --> 0
0.0014 --> 1.4E-3
2 --> 2
15 --> 1.5E1
3.14 --> 3.14
100 --> 1E2
1500000000 --> 1.5E9
```

Comment: That solves it for zero, but not, say, "1", which comes out as "1E0".

Comment: The `format` with his options is `#.######E0;1E-100;#.######E0`, you can just replace the zero format: `#.######E0;0;#.######E0` to achieve the same result. Zero is the easy case because it has it's own format.

Comment: In the end, I decided to subclass `NSNumberFormatter` to get rid of those `E0` instead

Comment: Me too, I  just put code in the view subclass and called one of two formatters depending on the mag of the number.